# When does BLAST fail to align 2 DNA sequences?

Tags: bioinformatics, homework, dna-sequencing, blast

This is an assignment that had confused me for a long time.  So I think you guys who study computational biology might be interested. The original question is:

> Find the two most similar DNA sequences of length 20 that Blast using a word length of 5 will fail to align.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

BLAST works by finding a perfect match between sequences of a length equal to this "word length" and then enlarging it in a standard way -- yet there will be no alignment without this perfectly matched word.

So in your case, you must look for two 20bp sequences with no common 5bp sub-sequence; for instance:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

and

```
AAAACAAAACAAAACAAAAC
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the standard answer.  But note that BLAST works  different with Protein. That's why it confused me for a while.

Comment: Is "word length" == k-tuple?

Comment: @StudentT Precisely k in k-tuple.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand BLAST correctly.

When using BLAST in DNA and protein, they are different. There is a threshold T in protein "seeding" step, which means the seeding sequence is not perfectly matched. However, it seems there is no T in seeding step and we are looking for perfect match and extend them to neighbouring sequence.

So, if there is no word length 5 exact match between these 2 sequence, BLAST will fail.

Comment: I am afraid i don't understand what you are trying to say here. Could you please clarify?